# @influxdata/giraffe - Table graph not rendering

Tags: reactjs, typeerror, influxdb

I've been trying to integrate **[giraffe](https://github.com/influxdata/giraffe)**'s **tableGraph**
in a app I was building but got this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')

Here are the configurations:

```js
    const tableLayer = {
    type: "table",
    timeZone: "America/Phoenix",
    tableTheme: "light",
    properties: {
      colors: DEFAULT_TABLE_COLORS,
      tableOptions: {
        fixFirstColumn: false,
        verticalTimeAxis: false,
        sortBy: {
          internalName: "_time",
          displayName: "_time",
          visible: true,
        },
      },
      fieldOptions: {
        internalName: "_time",
        displayName: "_time",
        visible: true,
      },
      timeFormat: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss ZZ",
      decimalPlaces: {
        isEnforced: true,
        digits: 3,
      },
    },
  };

  let config = {
    table: fluxResponse.table,
    layers: [tableLayer],
  };
```

And here is the rendered component:

```html
    <HoverTimeProvider>
          <div
            style={{
              width: "calc(70vw - 20px)",
              height: "calc(70vh - 20px)",
              margin: "40px",
            }}
          >
            <Plot config={config} />
          </div>
    </HoverTimeProvider>
```

Any ideas on what causes this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [TCL735](https://github.com/TCL735) in [issue #742](https://github.com/influxdata/giraffe/issues/742), the problem is in your `config`:

TableGraph doesn't have a property `table`, instead you should use property `fluxResponse`.

> Thus, you can pass your `fluxResponse` directly into the `fluxResponse` property and this should work.

You can find out more about it in the documentation on [Data Properties](https://github.com/influxdata/giraffe/blob/master/giraffe/README.md#data-properties): For TableGraph, the property `fluxResponse` is required "as it is the only property that represents the data", while property `table` is not used.

---

Since the naming is confusing, they consider to either rename TableGraph or delete it in favor of Simple Graph.